# How to make a responsive "Burger Icon" for navigation menu without using any framework?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive website and I'm using `&#9776;` to show a burger icon but it's not compatible with some browsers like phone browser and uc browser , So I want to make a responsive burger icon using HTML , CSS .

As I said I want it to be responsive so I don't want to use static width and height , I want it to be changed depends on the screen size , I'm using Media Queries.

There is an idea of using the following html :

```
<div class='navigation-icon'>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

Then each `<span>` is used to make one of the burger icon layers .

Comment: What css have you tried?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke , span{display:block;background-color:white;width:100%;height:2vh; and I replaced height with padding:2% 0;} , then I tried to add some margin or another '<span>' elements among the original 3 spans to make a distance among them , but then one of them become less in height (the three are not the same height)

Answer (score 1):

Well... I recommend you to use http://fontawesome.io/ or https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome if you want to use a CDN.

This is a library with a lot of fancy responsives icons and works on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

/* Icon 1 */

#nav-icon1, #nav-icon2, #nav-icon3, #nav-icon4 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon1 span, #nav-icon3 span, #nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}

#nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav-icon1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , Is there is a way to make the `<span>` height responsive dynamically like using % ?

Comment: that's pretty slick! I like it.

Comment: @Joe we can but using vw/vh

Comment: @JoshTheGray umm yea mate

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navigation-icon span {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='navigation-icon'>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can host your icon inside a responsive square, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class='navigation-icon'>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%; <== This will determine the size of your square and therefore of the elements in it, as long as their size is specified in % as well.
}

.square:before
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%; <== Leave this as is.
}
```

The css code above will make a perfect square that will adapt to the size of whatever it is nested in. Anything inside the square needs to be set to position: absolute though. or the square will turn into a rectangle.

Comment: @brain , thank you , but what about the `<span>` width and height ? what kind of values should I insert into their width and height to work with this ?

Comment: Take a look at this Pen I made, there are comments, feel free to experiment with the css. Resize the window to ascertain the adaptability of the code. https://codepen.io/BGGrieco/pen/JOjGVP?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class=menu></div>
<div class=menu></div>
<div class=menu></div>

.menu {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: black;
margin: 6px 0;
}
```